# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused when training PySpark model in Google Colab

Tags: python, pyspark, google-colaboratory, image-classification

I was trying to build a image classification model in PySpark with Google Colab TPU setting. I used featurizer to extract features of around 4000 pictures then use logistic regression to classify it as true or false, but it always stop at the "spark_model = sparkdn.fit(train)" line with the title's error code. However, my code work perfectly if i only do it with 20 pictures.

Sorry for the bad formatting, this is the first time I post a question.

The code is as below:

```
!pip install pyspark py4j
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, VectorIndexer,StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# create a spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Classification').getOrCreate()
# loaded image
train_one = spark.read.format("binaryFile") \
  .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.png") \
  .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
  .load("/content/drive/My Drive/machine_learning/train/true")

train_zero = spark.read.format("binaryFile") \
  .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.png") \
  .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
  .load("/content/drive/My Drive/machine_learning/train/false")

test_one = spark.read.format("binaryFile") \
  .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.png") \
  .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
  .load("/content/drive/My Drive/machine_learning/test/true")

test_zero = spark.read.format("binaryFile") \
  .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.png") \
  .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
  .load("/content/drive/My Drive/machine_learning/test/false")

# Set up ResNet50
model = ResNet50(include_top=False)
sc = spark.sparkContext
bc_model_weights = sc.broadcast(model.get_weights())

# Set up functions
def model_fn():

  model = ResNet50(weights=None, include_top=False)
  model.set_weights(bc_model_weights.value)
  return model

def preprocess(content):

  img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(content)).resize([224, 224])

  # Convert RGBA images to RGB
  if img.mode == 'RGBA':
      img = img.convert("RGB")

  arr = img_to_array(img)
  return preprocess_input(arr)

def featurize_series(model, content_series):

  input = np.stack(content_series.map(preprocess))
  preds = model.predict(input)
  # For some layers, output features will be multi-dimensional tensors.
  # We flatten the feature tensors to vectors for easier storage in Spark DataFrames.
  output = [p.flatten() for p in preds]
  return pd.Series(output)

@pandas_udf('array<float>', PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER)
def featurize_udf(content_series_iter):

  # With Scalar Iterator pandas UDFs, we can load the model once and then re-use it
  # for multiple data batches.  This amortizes the overhead of loading big models.
  model = model_fn()
  for content_series in content_series_iter:
    yield featurize_series(model, content_series)

# Pandas UDFs on large records (e.g., very large images) can run into Out Of Memory (OOM) errors.
# If you hit such errors in the cell below, try reducing the Arrow batch size via `maxRecordsPerBatch`.
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch", "1024")

# Extract features of images from 2 dataframe
train_one_feature = train_one.repartition(16).select(col("path"), featurize_udf("content").alias("features"))
train_zero_feature = train_zero.repartition(16).select(col("path"), featurize_udf("content").alias("features"))
test_one_feature = test_one.repartition(16).select(col("path"), featurize_udf("content").alias("features"))
test_zero_feature = test_zero.repartition(16).select(col("path"), featurize_udf("content").alias("features"))
list_to_vector_udf = udf(lambda l: Vectors.dense(l), VectorUDT())
train_one_feature = train_one_feature.select(
   col("path"),
    list_to_vector_udf(train_one_feature["features"]).alias("features")
)
train_zero_feature = train_zero_feature.select(
   col("path"),
    list_to_vector_udf(train_zero_feature["features"]).alias("features")
)
test_one_feature = test_one_feature.select(
   col("path"),
    list_to_vector_udf(test_one_feature["features"]).alias("features")
)
test_zero_feature = test_zero_feature.select(
   col("path"),
    list_to_vector_udf(test_zero_feature["features"]).alias("features")
)
# Label the benign and malignant image as 0 in "normal" column, normal image as 1
train_one_feature = train_one_feature.withColumn("normal",lit(1))
train_zero_feature = train_zero_feature.withColumn("normal",lit(0))
test_one_feature = test_one_feature.withColumn("normal",lit(1))
test_zero_feature = test_zero_feature.withColumn("normal",lit(0))

# Combine and random split the 2 dataframe
train = train_one_feature.union(train_zero_feature)
test = test_one_feature.union(test_zero_feature)

# Train the logistic regression and predict on test dataset
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['features'], outputCol="featuresModel")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=5, regParam=0.03,
                        elasticNetParam=0.5, labelCol="normal", featuresCol="featuresModel")
sparkdn = Pipeline(stages=[vectorAssembler,lr])
spark_model = sparkdn.fit(train) # start fitting or training
```

Output is

```
Collecting pyspark
  Downloading pyspark-3.4.1.tar.gz (310.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 310.8/310.8 MB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: py4j in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (0.10.9.7)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyspark
  Building wheel for pyspark (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pyspark: filename=pyspark-3.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=311285388 sha256=9f9ebd83830d65c9f946be7e8dc20a5616e6ef64c0bec454460d814c56715539
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/0d/77/a3/ff2f74cc9ab41f8f594dabf0579c2a7c6de920d584206e0834
Successfully built pyspark
Installing collected packages: pyspark
Successfully installed pyspark-3.4.1
Mounted at /content/drive
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/resnet/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
94765736/94765736 [==============================] - 0s 0us/step
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/pandas/functions.py:399: UserWarning: In Python 3.6+ and Spark 3.0+, it is preferred to specify type hints for pandas UDF instead of specifying pandas UDF type which will be deprecated in the future releases. See SPARK-28264 for more details.
  warnings.warn(
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52616)
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-47567e823356>", line 143, in <cell line: 143>
    spark_model = sparkdn.fit(train) # start fitting or training
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 205, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 134, in _fit
    model = stage.fit(dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 205, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 381, in _fit
    java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 378, in _fit_java
    return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: <unprintable Py4JJavaError object>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2099, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'Py4JJavaError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/clientserver.py", line 516, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1038, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/clientserver.py", line 539, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending or receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 281, in handle
    poll(accum_updates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 253, in poll
    if func():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 257, in accum_updates
    num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/serializers.py", line 596, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
----------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

<ipython-input-1-47567e823356> in <cell line: 143>()
    142 sparkdn = Pipeline(stages=[vectorAssembler,lr])
--> 143 spark_model = sparkdn.fit(train) # start fitting or training
    144 

15 frames
<class 'str'>: (<class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>, ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/clientserver.py in connect_to_java_server(self)
    436                 self.socket = self.ssl_context.wrap_socket(
    437                     self.socket, server_hostname=self.java_address)
--> 438             self.socket.connect((self.java_address, self.java_port))
    439             self.stream = self.socket.makefile("rb")
    440             self.is_connected = True

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```